# Actionscript 3.0 : Strange default hour

Tags: actionscript, counter

I want to create a timeup counter in flash with actionscript. Minutes / Seconds display well but problem is that hours start with 1 instead of 0. This the code:

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.globalization.DateTimeFormatter;

var timer:Timer = new Timer(100);
timer.start();
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerTickHandler);
var timerCount:int = 0;

function timerTickHandler(Event:TimerEvent):void
{
    timerCount += 100;
    toTimeCode(timerCount);
}

function toTimeCode(milliseconds:int) : void {
    //create a date object using the elapsed milliseconds
    var time:Date = new Date(milliseconds);

    //define minutes/seconds/mseconds
    var hours:String = String(time.hours);
    var minutes:String = String(time.minutes);
    var seconds:String = String(time.seconds);


    //add zero if neccecary, for example: 2:3.5 becomes 02:03.5
    hours = (hours.length != 2) ? '0'+hours : hours;
    minutes = (minutes.length != 2) ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
    seconds = (seconds.length != 2) ? '0'+seconds : seconds;




    //display elapsed time on in a textfield on stage
    timer_txt.text = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

}
```

I tried everything but still have hour = 1 when counter starts!!!

Comment: That code seems to work correctly for me. Does the 1 stay, or is it just there momentarily? Have you tried seeing what `trace(hours);` comes out as?

Comment: hours starts with value 1, next values are 2,3,4,5... So problem is only initial value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be getting an hour offset because of `Date` handling daylight saving time automatically. Try using the UTC values instead:

```
var hours:String = String(time.hoursUTC);
var minutes:String = String(time.minutesUTC);
var seconds:String = String(time.secondsUTC);
```

Comment: Because timer if for live broadcasting, I want users to be able to see the current time of the broadcast. There's no problem for calculating the elapsed time since the beginning of the live, but when I initiate my timer, how can I start it with x seconds / minutes. For example if broadcast is started since 15 minutes and 12 seconds, when the timer is displayed, if should start with 00:15:12 instead of 00:00:00

Comment: You could just set your `timerCount` to the start time in milliseconds. (So, 15 * 60 * 1000 + 12 * 1000). By the way, you can mark your question as "answered" if you click the tick next to this answer. Cheers.